# Query to delete records older than n active dates from each group

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a dataset that I need to prune on a daily basis.  It is populated from a process that writes records into a table periodically.

I currently have a simple query that does this:

```
DELETE FROM dataTable WHERE entryDate < dateadd(day, -5, GETDATE())
```

But the problem is that the process is unreliable; there may be days where no data is written at all.

So what I really need is a query that goes back 5 (possibly non-consecutive) *days in which data is written,* not 5 calendar days.

For example, if I run the following query:

```
SELECT cast(entryDate  as date) as LogDate
  FROM dataTable
  group by category, cast(entryDate as date)
  order by cast(entryDate as date) desc
```

I might get as a result:

```
Category    Date
Foo        2015-11-30
Foo        2015-11-29
Foo        2015-11-26
Foo        2015-11-25
Foo        2015-11-21
Foo        2015-11-20  <-- Start Pruning here, not the 25th.
Foo        2015-11-19
Foo        2015-11-18

Bar        2015-11-30
Bar        2015-11-29
Bar        2015-11-28
Bar        2015-11-27
Bar        2015-11-26
Bar        2015-11-25  <-- This one is OK to prune at the 25th.
Bar        2015-11-24
Bar        2015-11-23
```

I need the query to go all the way back to the 20th before it deletes.

Comment: One way is to determine the "pruning date" with a sub-query.

Comment: Why you do not use `Limit` ?
`DELETE FROM dataTable WHERE entryDate IN (--your query-- + LIMIT 5)`

Comment: `DELETE FROM dataTable WHERE entryDate IN (SELECT cast(entryDate  as date) as LogDate
  FROM dataTable
  group by anotherField, cast(entryDate as date)
  order by cast(entryDate as date) desc LIMIT 5)`

Comment: @wajeeh "Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to get the last 5 days when the table had an entry. Then delete based on the generated numbers.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/654cb/1)

```
with rownums as (SELECT row_number() over(partition by category order by cast(entryDate as date) desc) as rn
                 ,*
                 FROM dataTable
)
delete from rownums where rn <= 5 --use > 5 for records prior to the last 5 days
```

Use `dense_rank` to number the rows if there can be multiple entries per day.

```
with rownums as (SELECT dense_rank() over(partition by category order by cast(entryDate as date) desc) as rn
                     ,*
                 FROM dataTable)
delete from rownums where rn > 5;
```

Comment: Damn, I just realized that I need to group by another field first.  So the 5 most recent has to be over each group.

Comment: yes, you can use a `partition by` in `row_number` in that case

Comment: If you add that, I'll go ahead and accept (you can just make up a name for the partitioned column), and I'll fix up my question accordingly.  Thanks,  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ah, I just realized why it's returning dates it shouldn't... The process can write more than once per day to the table.

Comment: @RobertHarvey..use `dense_rank()` in that case. `dense_rank() over(partition by somecolumn order by cast(entryDate as date) desc)`

Answer (score 1):

Try maybe something like this.

```
;WITH orderedDates (LogDate, RowNum)
AS 
(
SELECT [CACHEDATE] AS LogDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CACHEDATE DESC) AS RowNum
FROM
dataTable
GROUP BY CACHEDATE
)
DELETE dataTable
WHERE CACHEDATE IN
(SELECT LogDate FROM orderedDates
WHERE ROWNUM > 5) --or however many you need to go back
```

Comment: There's another group by needed.  Sorry about that.